# Having trouble using strtok on stdin

Tags: c

I'm having an unusually hard time reading from std, splitting on spaces, then putting those tokens into an array. (Ignore the allocation of 80 bytes, this is just temporary for testing)

```
char* inputLine = (char*)malloc(80);
char* commands[80];
char* input;
int i;
fgets(inputLine, 80, stdin);
input = strtok(inputLine, " \n");
for (i=0; input != NULL; i++) {
    memcpy(commands[i], input, sizeof(input));
    input = strtok(NULL, " \n");
}
```

With input of

```
command1 command2 command3
```

The output should be

```
commands[0] = "command1" 
commands[1] = "command2" 
commands[2] = "command3"
```

However, the output I get is

```
commands[0] = "command1"
commands[1] = ""
commands[2] = "command3"
```

When stepping through the debugger, I can see that commands[0] and commands[1] get populated correctly. However, when the last memcpy gets executed, it assigns command[2] and erases command[1].

My experience with C is very limited, I appreciate someone pointing out my stupid mistake!

Comment: A pointer is not an array. What do you think `sizeof(input)` yields?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears that you have not allocated memory to store the commands. You have only allocated an array of pointers, so your behavior is actually undefined. The fix is to allocate memory and initialize it.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(){
    char* inputLine = (char*)malloc(80);
    char* commands[80];
    char* input;
    int i;
    int numCommands = 0;
    fgets(inputLine, 80, stdin);
    input = strtok(inputLine, " \n");
    for (i=0; input != NULL; i++) {
        numCommands++;
        commands[i] = malloc(strlen(input) + 1);
        strncpy(commands[i], input, strlen(input));
        input = strtok(NULL, " \n");
    }

    for (i = 0; i < numCommands; i++) {
        puts(commands[i]);
    }
}
```

Comment: For the love of monkeys use `strncpy()` and `strlen()` when allocating memory.

Comment: Sorry, I'll fix this. I just added the relevant lines.

Comment: Thank you for that, I'm actually tinkering right now to refresh myself on manual memory management and this is exactly the reason.

Comment: @BLUEPIXY It's because I have 3 command line args specified in my question

Comment: @jlee It is not a reason.

Comment: Don't use `strncpy` unless you must work with legacy applications using fixed-length character fields that are not null-terminated. When you work with strings, use `strcpy` or `snprintf`.

Comment: that's not how strtok works. there is a better way to do this.

Comment: You forgot to null-terminate `commands[i]`. suggest changing `strncpy` to `strcpy` which does copy the null terminator.  (This is a perfect example of why the latter is a safer function)

Answer (score 0):

So here is another solution of reading stdin and putting it into an arrary of tokens split by whitespaces:

```
int main(void)
{
        char *line = NULL, *buf = NULL;
        size_t len = 0;
        size_t bufpos = 0, buflen = 0;
        ssize_t bytes = 0;
        char *p;
        char **command = NULL;
        size_t count = 0;
        int k;

        while((bytes = getline(&line, &len, stdin)) != -1)  {
                fprintf(stderr, "buf:%p, bufpos:%lu, buflen: %lu\n", buf, bufpos, buflen);
                buflen += bytes;
                buf = realloc(buf, buflen);
                strncpy(buf+bufpos, line, bytes);
                *(buf+bufpos+bytes-1) = ' '; /* change \n at the end to a space */
                bufpos = buflen;
        }

        free(line);

        if(buflen == 0) {
                exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }

        if(buf[buflen-1] == ' ')
                buf[buflen-1] = 0;

        command = malloc(sizeof(char *)); /* at least one command is there */

        /* mark all the commands */
        command[0] = buf;
        count = 1;
        for(p = buf; *p != 0; p++) {
                int delimit = 0;

                /* eatup consecutive whitespaces */
                while(isspace(*p)) {
                        delimit = 1;
                        *p = 0;
                        p++;
                        if(!*p || !isspace(*p))
                                break;
                }

                if(delimit) {
                        command = realloc(command, (1+count)*sizeof(char *));
                        command[count] = p;

                        count++;
                }
        }

        for (k = 0; k < count; k++) {
                fprintf(stdout, "%d : %s\n", k, command[k]);
        }

        free(command);
        free(buf);

        return 0;
}
```

~

A few things to note:

1. This uses `getline`, which is a very safe way to read strings dynamically.
2. The `command` array is an array of pointers that points into various spots of `buf` array which contains everything that's read in. Which means that you're not reallocating strings all over the place.  You can now pass `buf` to `strtok` or, do what I did in the `for` loop that allocates and assigns commands.
3. This has more control on how you delimit the commmands
4. You can make this into a reenterant function.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to allocate so much memory.  Just do

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main()
{
    char line[1024];

    while(fgets(line, sizeof line, stdin)) {
        char *command[80];
        int n_command = 0, i;
        char *p;
        for (p = strtok(line, " \n"); p && (n_command < 80); p = strtok(NULL, " \n"))
            command[n_command++] = p;
        for (i = 0; i < n_command; i++)
            printf("[%s]", command[i]);
        puts(""); /* final end of line to stdout */
    }
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
} /* main */
```

as you can use a static size (large enough for large lines) and a maximum number of `command` entries.  Note that command entries are discarded when reaching the maximum of 80 entries, and a line is broken in pieces of 1024 characters each, if they are longer.  This example only ilustrates the use of `strtok(3)` in a `for` loop.

```
$ pru_$$ | sed 's/^/    /'
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet sed. Arcu ac quam. Posuere malesuada in. Morbi et feugiat libero mauris pellentesque. Vulputate a vel et cupidatat mi mi.

Praesent eget vestibulum mauris imperdiet et dolor aliquam dui. Ultrices donec nascetur. Ante neque hymenaeos. Quis sed placerat at ac et. Purus elementum vestibulum nunc.

Et id eu tellus at libero enim odio et. Nec enim maecenas ac pellentesque magna placerat culpa ut. Dolor at malesuada justo est ut tellus sapien nunc. Diam saepe fermentum. Vivamus dolor adipiscing vitae wisi vivamus. Diam consequat lobortis. Integer habitasse feugiat. Non in minima. Lacus odio odio urna nunc.
[Lorem] [ipsum] [dolor] [sit] [amet] [sed.] [Arcu] [ac] [quam.] [Posuere] [malesuada] [in.] [Morbi] [et] [feugiat] [libero] [mauris] [pellentesque.] [Vulputate] [a] [vel] [et] [cupidatat] [mi] [mi.]

[Praesent] [eget] [vestibulum] [mauris] [imperdiet] [et] [dolor] [aliquam] [dui.] [Ultrices] [donec] [nascetur.] [Ante] [neque] [hymenaeos.] [Quis] [sed] [placerat] [at] [ac] [et.] [Purus] [elementum] [vestibulum] [nunc.]

[Et] [id] [eu] [tellus] [at] [libero] [enim] [odio] [et.] [Nec] [enim] [maecenas] [ac] [pellentesque] [magna] [placerat] [culpa] [ut.] [Dolor] [at] [malesuada] [justo] [est] [ut] [tellus] [sapien] [nunc.] [Diam] [saepe] [fermentum.] [Vivamus] [dolor] [adipiscing] [vitae] [wisi] [vivamus.] [Diam] [consequat] [lobortis.] [Integer] [habitasse] [feugiat.] [Non] [in] [minima.] [Lacus] [odio] [odio] [urna] [nunc.]
```